# Simple but confusing: Finding the $n$th term of a sequence, given that the sum of the $1$st to $n$th terms is $3n^2-2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

So the question is the following:

> Given that $S_n = 3n^2 - 2$ , Find the nth term of the sequence $a_n$.
>
> $S_n$ is the sum of the sequence from $1$ to $n$.

I know that the answer should be an arithmetic sequence, because all the choices are as such, and anyway we know that from the form of $S_n$.

The weird thing is that if we solve it this way: $S_n - S_{n-1} = a_n$ , We know that the formula for the sum of an arithmetic sequence is :

$$S_n = \frac {n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$$

Using this and calculating $S_n - S_{n-1}$ for   $S_n = 3n^2 - 2$ , we get $a_n = 6n-3$ and where $a_1 = 3$

However, if we work backward to verify the answer, starting from $a_n = 6n-3$ and plugging that into the general formula $S_n = \frac {n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$ , we get:

$$S_n = \frac {n(a_1 + a_n)}{2} =\frac {n(3 + 6n-3)}{2} = 3n^2$$

Which works perfectly if we try out a few values for example $S_3 = 27$ , and $a_1 = 3, a_2 = 9, a_3 = 15 ,$  so  $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 3 + 9 + 15 = 27$

But the sequence $6n-3$ does not work with $S_n = 3n^2 - 2$ and we can tell that from $S_1 = 1$ which is not equal to $a_1 = 3$

In fact I then realized that if we began with a general sum $S_n = 3n^2 - k$ where $k$ is any constant, then solving for $a_n$ the same way above ($S_n - S_{n-1}$) will give the same answer $6n-3$ because anyway $k$ will always disappear when finding the difference $S_n - S_{n-1}$

Either I am committing an extremely sneaky mistake, or in fact the question is mistaken from the beginning i.e it has the wrong answers or $S_n$.

So how can this be exactly?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't specified "Find the $n$'th term where $n>1$ of $a_n$?"  $a_1$ and $S_1$ may just be a special case that doesn't fit the pattern otherwise.

Comment: There must be a mistake in the $S_n$ formula as $n$ should be a factor

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the question means that the sum $S_n$ of the first $n$ terms of the sequence is given by $S_n=3n^2-2$ for $n\geq 1$. Indeed, the sum of $0$ terms of anything must be $0$, so the formula can't work for $n=0$ (where it gives $-2$).

Now your calculation for the $n$th term involves substituting ${n-1}$ into the formula, so this is only valid if $n-1\geq 1$, i.e. $n\geq 2$. It doesn't give the correct value for $n=1$.

So the $n$th term of your sequence is $a_n=6n-3$ for $n\geq2$ and (just using the value of $S_1$) $a_n=1$ for $n=1$.

Comment: This gives us the sequence $1, 9, 15, ...$ which is not an arithmetic sequence

Comment: @Vasili no it isn't, but it is the unique sequence with those partial sums. The quoted question doesn't say it should be an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: It should be an arithmetic sequence because this is an MCQ question and all the answers are arithmetic sequences.

Comment: @AmerHijazi Well, either the question or the answer should specify "the $n$th term where $n\geq 2$". But what I have written is the correct answer to the question as posed.

Comment: Your answer will work indeed. However, it contradicts the assumption that it is an arithmetic sequence. Your answer is an arithmetic sequence but with a special condition for the initial value so it looks like an awkward arithmetic sequence.

Comment: @AmerHijazi It contradicts *your* assumption that it is an arithmetic sequence. The question doesn't tell you to assume that.

Comment: Brother your answer is literally an arithmetic sequence. In fact there is no other form of a sequence that can work here. The question is an MCQ question and ALL the choices there are arithmetic sequences. Do you understand why I am assuming it is one?

Answer (score 2):

As @Vasili commented, if $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms of an arithmetic progression then $n$ should be a factor (hence $S_n$ cannot have a nonzero constant term like in $3n^2-2$).

Indeed,
$$a+(a+r)+(a+2r)+\dots+(a+(n-1)r)=\frac{n(2a+(n-1)r)}2=n(b+nc)$$
where $b=a-\frac r2$ and $c=\frac r2$.

Comment: You and @Vasili are right, I first recognized that it is impossible that there is no $n$ factor if the sequence starts from $n=1$.  However, this could happen if we suppose it starts from 0. Even if we did in this example, the general formula will include $n+1$ instead of $n$ and this will still give $3n^2 -3$ if the sequence is $a_n = 6n-3$

Comment: Sure, but you specified "$S_n$
 is the sum of the sequence from $1$
 to $n$", not from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: Yes I know. I am justifying that $6n-3$ has to also be wrong EVEN IF we go beyond the scope of the question. What I am thinking now is that $S_n = 3n^2 -2$ is actually an impossible formula for any arithmetic sequence as I just proved it using the simple general formula I gave, starting either from $0$ or $1$. Starting from a false assumption creates all this confusion.